# Android Studio , how to control a website through a mobile app

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to Android studio and i was wondering that, how can I control a website through an android app.
For example: there is a listbox on the website with values and I want to select a value through my app 
and press a submit button ,without opening the interface.
is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should connect your application and website to same database on server.with application you change the values on database and you can see the result on website.you will need related libraries or classes to implement network connection between android app and server like:retrofit or volley

Comment: Without server. Like get items from the website to the app,fill fields through the app.

Comment: If you mean to load website on mobile and change the values as a user u can use WebView.